# Atlas is still showing old relays

Tags: atlas

i was playing around with running a tor relay on several servers.

So now that im finished i would like to get rid of the old relays wich still show up in atlas.
One of the relays is down for about 4 days.

Is there a general downtime timeout and they disappear after some time or do i have to revoke the keys manually?

If i have to revoke the keys how would i do that?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about relays is generally archived permanently. Atlas should show the relay as offline, but the archives will continue to be available.